# How to set up a desktop GUI with an Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, x11

I need to get familiar with some software that doesn't run on any of my home machines (windows/mac). So I decided to spin up an EC2 instance and try it there.

However, getting EC2 to support a remote desktop session is proving to be harder than it has a right to be.  I have tried techniques found through web searches but all are out of date and no longer relevant.

So far I have tried all these suggested solutions - none have worked so far:

- [This one fails with timeout](http://www.vandorp.biz/2012/01/installing-a-lightweight-lxdevnc-desktop-environment-on-your-ubuntudebian-vps/#.U4GkRt8wGNA), even with port open, logs say nothing.
- [With this one](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/AWS/AWS_Tips/AWS_Management/AWS_12.shtml), the packages suggested are not available.

> ```
> [ec2-user@ip-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ~]$ yum groups list
> Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
> Installed groups:
>    Editors
>    Legacy UNIX compatibility
>    Mail Server
>    Network Servers
>    Perl Support
>    System Tools
> Available Groups:
>    Console internet tools
>    DNS Name Server
>    Development Libraries
>    Development tools
>    FTP Server
>    Java Development
>    MySQL Database
>    MySQL Database client
>    NFS file server
>    Networking Tools
>    PHP Support
>    Performance Tools
>    PostgreSQL Database client (version 8)
>    PostgreSQL Database server (version 8)
>    Scientific support
>    TeX support
>    Technical Writing
>    Web Server
>    Web Servlet Engine
> Done
> ```

Nothing that says it will give me an X session.

- Tried some other things [such as this](http://michaelhallsmoore.com/blog/Desktop-Ubuntu-in-Amazon-EC2-The-Right-Way): The community ami he suggests does not exist anymore.
- Tried [this as well](http://activeintelligence.org/blog/archive/remote-graphical-linux-desktop-on-ec2): freenx is no longer around, no machine server is now 4.3 and doesn't seem to work in the free version.
- x2go fails also.
- also tried [this one](https://www.nomachine.com/AR10K00710): https://www.nomachine.com/AR10K00710.  Xvfb is not available.

Has anybody worked the kinks out of the setup and got it working recently?

P.S. A few people asked why not use a VirtualBox VM - forgot to mention that I definitely tried that first and for whatever reason none of them worked.  I started with the most recent and worked backwards through each version - could not get them to launch or run.  (My machine is a Cintiq Companion with Windows 8).

Comment: There is nothing "special" about an ec2 instance. It's a linux server. As long as you install the requisite software and ensure that firewall rules are not interfering, you can easily use a GUI. As an aside, though, why not just install VirtualBox on your machine and play with a local VM?

Comment: @EEAA agreed, why bother with EC2 for something that simple when VMs are local, fast, and you get full control?

Comment: +1 for using a local VM. That said, `yum repolist` will tell you what repos you're subscribed to, you're probably just missing one that has the X11/gnome/kde packages you want.

Comment: +1 somewhat awesome username.

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention that I tried to use a VM - I spent days installing every version working backwards from the latest to several major releases back.  None would work on my machine.   I have a Cintiq Companion with Windows 8 and could not for the life of me get any version of virtual box to work.

Comment: I would recomend a local VM too, but if you really want to use X on EC2, why not install VNC-Server on it?

Comment: I have managed to get this working before using an Ubuntu instance and VNC.  The method I used was similar to the following:  http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/setting-up-vnc-on-ubuntu-in-the-amazon-ec2.html

Comment: @Matt.  Thank you - I tried your suggested link - still had to fiddle and funk around but got something going at last

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following suggestion from Matt in the comments

Set up an SSH tunnel plus a local private key using instructions from this link:  http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/setting-up-vnc-on-ubuntu-in-the-amazon-ec2-page-2.html

on ec2 ran these installers (not sure which ones are overkill - only that it eventually worked)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
sudo apt-get install x11vnc
x11vnc -storepasswd
sudo apt-get install gnome-core gnome-session-fallback

vncserver
vncserver -kill :1  #(to get the default xstartup file)
```

edit $HOME/.vnc/xstartup to look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80×24+10+10 -ls -title “$VNCDESKTOP Desktop” &
#x-window-manager &
```

had to set a password for the ubuntu user (gnome desktop seems to need this?)

```
sudo passwd ubuntu
```

had to ***reboot*** the instance

then ran

```
 sudo x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -usepw
```

Then I could connect via TightVNC and see the Ubuntu desktop

Not sure what other troubles I may run into, but at least I got this far

Thank you Matt

Comment: I followed every step of yours. could you please elaborate how too cnnect using tightVNC?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you said you tried X2Go but it failed; I am using it successfully right now on two Ubuntu 14.04 instances, one is an EC2 micro on AWS, the other is a small DigitalOcean droplet (it also works on a number of other distros, but you'll have to modify step 3 below based on [these instructions](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:installation:x2goserver)). While VNC will certainly work, X2go is faster and much more responsive, as well as supporting SSH proxy by default.

I went through the exact same frustration of finding outdated or irrelevant articles and suggestions for setting up a cloud desktop, but once I figured out the X2Go solution, its actually very simple to get up and running in ~10 mins.

Here are the steps I used to set everything up:

1. SSH key -- since it's a remote server, you should already be able to login via SSH normally, but if not, you'll need an SSH login via RSA key for a user with `sudo` privileges
2. System update -- not required, but depending on when you last updated the remote machine, doing so now may avoid incompatibilities or headaches:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
3. Install X2Go Server -- create a new file on the remote machine and paste the following contents into it:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   # note: this script may take some time to run, particularly
   # the steps involving the install of xubuntu as it has many
   # packages included as dependencies

   printf "\ninstalling required packages...\n"
   sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
   sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

   printf "\ninstalling xubuntu...\n"
   sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop

   printf "\nadding x2go ppa repository...\n"
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable
   sudo apt-get update

   printf "\ninstalling x2go server...\n"
   sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession

   printf "\nxubuntu and x2go server have been installed.\n"
   echo "don't forget to reboot your instance as well!"
   ```

   Execute the file to install everything (`. ./<filename>`); you may need to modify the file permissions first to make it executable -- typically I've had it take between 5-10 minutes, however, ymmv
4. Install X2Go Client -- the last step is to install the client for the OS you want to access the remote machine from; installation instructions for Windows, Mac, and various flavors of Linux can be found [here](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:installation:x2goclient)

Now you can use the client to connect to the machine via your configured host, user, key, port and access your GUI cloud desktop; make sure you select `XFCE` as the session type when setting up the connection.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using NoMachine on an Amazon instance, you should follow the instructions here:
https://www.nomachine.com/AR10K00710 (NoMachine on headless servers)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: forgot to include that one in the list of things I already tried.  Xvfb  is not available

Answer (score -3):

> No, you can't. Amazon Linux does not have a Repo for X-server packages. Also, It was meant to be used for Server side roles and hence all he X related stuff is not available.

Thanks slayedbylucifer

Form https://stackoverflow.com/a/21273694/1105231